# Content links are breaking

Tags: uri

I've been hired by a firm as an entry level developer/seo/content marketing person and part of my responsibility includes their Drupal (6.X) CMS. I'm working my way through the 'The Definitive Guide to Drupal 7' and I've been making only small iterative changes so far while I'm getting the hang of everything. Today though, I have a bit of an issue which I could use some help on.

Some of the content links are breaking and it is due (I believe) to the way they have Drupal configured as well as my own green-ness. For example, the site's content area (the `<front>`) is called www.drupal.com/blog but the name of the server that hosts Drupal is server.drupal.com. Newer content and some of the older content is being automatically aliased to server.drupal.com and so is only viewable when a user (admin) is logged in. So, when a video node is posted, it is aliased as, for example, server.drupal.com/videos/awesome-video but when www.drupal.com/videos/awesome-video is entered into the URL as an anon user it throws a 404. No bueno.

The URL Alias module automattically sets server.drupal.com as the default base pathway and only allows me to set the /videos/awesome-video part of the alias.

Answer (score 0):

Your woes are most likely coming from apache (or whichever web server you are using) unless you are using the domain module. Either your .htacces file or virtual host (depending on whether you have "AllowOverride" on in apache) should be setup to route requests through 'example.com' and not 'server.example.com'.

Are you on a VPS or shared host? What flavor of Linux are you using?

Comment: Hey acouch, thanks for your reply. We are running a WIMP stack at the present, though I plan to eventually switch us over to a WAMP stack once I know what I'm doing. We have a number of servers in here, this one in particular is devoted to the CMS and a few of the other landing pages, etc. Drupal is the only thing using any open source software, everything else is run on MS. Here's another example. I have set up a new vocabulary called 'Products' and added product terms to it.

Comment: The individual node page works just fine, ie "www.drupal.com/blog/content-x". But the menu I created to house and direct users to pages that display all nodes for a certain product terms are being created to 'server.drupal.com/products/content-x."

Comment: Are you using hook_menu or the menu system? Is there anything in settigs.php that has 'server.drupal.com' like $base_url? My guess is that this is due to your IIS settings because Drupal doesn't care about your host address unless you explicitly tell it to. See: http://drupal.org/node/3854

Answer (score 0):

As acouch noted check your settings.php (at sites/default/ folder) and make sure that `$base_url` is not pointing to server.drupal.com. Even if it's commented out, try uncommenting it and put drupal.com as the `$base_url`. That way you will be forcing the url of your site.